# using RenderFormat.IsInteractive in SSRS query

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am creating a SSRS report where I require to call different queries based on some condition. mainly with `Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive`.
If `Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive` is true call 1st query block otherwise other query block.
In query itself it is not possible to create `IF` condition using Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive. so I tried creating report variable and parameter with default value of `Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive` but both giving error of `query refers to the global variable RenderFormat, which is not valid for this type of report item expression`.
Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Do both blocks have the same structure? If so you could mark every block in a column True for IsInteractive or False otherwise. Using UNION operator you can create one dataset from both blocks. Then just use a filter to get only the interactive or not interactive rows. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: The RenderFormat variable won't work in a lot of places in a report, namely things that are done in data retrieval or processing.  It won't even work as an expression for a subreport parameter, which is a functional workaround in other cases.  So you can use it as part of a textbox expression, but not a parameter, calculated field, or an expression for report properties.

Comment: @alejandro-zuleta, report is like currently it displays 18 columns but while exporting it exports with 32 columns. so 14 columns made hidden using `RenderFormat.IsInteractive`. there would be around million of records so i am working on logic to fetch only 18 columns (other NULL) while displaying on report and fetch all while exporting. i know million records in report is not advisable but after all its client's requirement.

Comment: You can use a link to specify both parameters and the render format.  If that's acceptable, you can use a formatting parameter, as well as place the link on the report itself if desired.  The link would look like this, replacing names where appropriate: `http://host/ReportServer_Instance?/ReportFolder/Million%20Row%20Report&ExportFormat=True&rs:Format=Excel`

Comment: @bitnine, Currently it's not possible to add link in report. but +1 for it. It will give it try to see how this link work just to learn.